# Solr - Get the counts group by field for every month

Tags: search, solr, lucene, solr4, faceted-search

I need to get the results grouped by company for every year. 
I tried below query :

```
http://localhost:8080/solr/select?q=&fq=status_created_at:[2011-12-31T4:00:00Z TO 2016-04-13T4:00:00Z] AND -company:(20 26 27 536)&facet=true&facet.field=company&facet.date=status_created_at&facet.date.start=2012-01-01T4:00:00Z&facet.date.end=2016-4-12T4:00:00Z&facet.date.gap=+1MONTH&fl=id&wt=json&rows=0&start=0&defType=dismax&qf=text
```

I expect the result to return like this

```
{ 2015: {"1":123, "2":412}, 2014: {"1":123, "2":412}, }
```

But the query does not give expected results. I understand my requirement is combination `Grouping`+`Faceting` but do not know how to fine tune the query.

Help me to solve this.